# can not start ipython notebook from anaconda

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have installed anaconda into my home directory and added the path to PATH os variable

and installed ipython notebook in anaconda with command

```
conda install ipython-notebook
```

it works fine

after that I opened terminal and typed in

```
ipython notebook
```

it reported

```
Could not start notebook. Please install ipython-notebook
```

Have I done something wrong on the installation?

The output of

```
conda list | grep ipython
```

is

```
ipython                   2.3.1                    py27_0  
ipython-notebook          2.3.1                    py27_0  
ipython-qtconsole         2.2.0                    py27_0
```

Comment: could you verify it's installed in that environment. `conda list | grep ipython` should verify

Comment: Make sure your `ipython` is the conda IPython. Does `which ipython` show the path to your Anaconda directory?

Comment: @asmeurer thank you for your hint. The problem is solved, exactly following your suggestion

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could be a couple of things:

conda installs ipython into the active conda environment.  If bash had seen a previous invocation of ipython it might have that location hashed.

Run `hash -r` to clear the shell hashed lookups after installing anything that places a new executable in your path.  Things like:

- ipython
- pip
- binstar
- ...

Comment: thank you for your response @Phil Cooper. I have run hash -r in terminal and restart it, but still the same error report.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but still just want to put my answer here so that it may be useful for somebody who has the same question.

Ipython notebook has become jupyter notebook with the latest installation of Anaconda (v3.x).

So going forward, the command "ipython notebook" executed either in the terminal or in the powershell will open Jupyter notebook only